# add column to dataframes from 1 to unique length of existing grouped rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, col

Here is my example df:

```
df = read.table(text = 'colA 
22
22
22
45
45
11
11
87
90
110
32
32', header = TRUE)
```

I just need to add a new col based on colA with values from 1 to the unique length of colA.

Expected output:

```
   colA   newCol 
    22     1
    22     1
    22     1
    45     2
    45     2
    11     3
    11     3
    87     4
    90     5
    110    6 
    32     7
    32     7
```

Here is what I tried without succes:

```
library(dplyr)
new_df = df %>%
  group_by(colA) %>% 
  mutate(newCol = seq(1, length(unique(df$colA)), by = 1))
```

Thanks

Comment: Are the values of cola clustered as in your example, or is it possible that you might have a sequence like    22  45  22 ? Can you come back to a value?

Comment: they are clustered. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newcol = c(1, 1+cumsum(diff(df$colA) != 0))
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 7
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dplyr` package has a function to get indices of group:

```
df$newcol = group_indices(df,colA)
```

This returns:

```
    colA newcol
1    22      2
2    22      2
3    22      2
4    45      4
5    45      4
6    11      1
7    11      1
8    87      5
9    90      6
10  110      7
11   32      3
12   32      3
```

Though the index is not ordered according to the order of appearance.

You can also do it using `factor`:

```
df$newcol = as.numeric(factor(df$colA,levels=unique(df$colA)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option: You can capitalize on the fact that factors are associated with underlying integers. First create a new factor variable with the same levels as the column, then transform it to numeric.

```
newCol <- factor(df$colA, 
    levels = unique(df$colA))

df$newCol <- as.numeric(newCol)
df

   colA newCol
1    22      1
2    22      1
3    22      1
4    45      2
5    45      2
6    11      3
7    11      3
8    87      4
9    90      5
10  110      6
11   32      7
12   32      7
```